# Cabinet vs voting booth

Tags: word-choice

I came across the following sentence in a text-book:
"Sign the list, take your voting paper and go to the cabinet."
I've checked my dictionaries whether a cabinet also means a voting booth or not but I couldn't find anything.
Maybe the writer meant "cabin". What do you think?
I guess, in this sentence we can either use "voting booth" or "polling booth".

Comment: Yes. It's a booth, voting booth if you want to be more precise. I wouldn't even say "voting paper" but "voting slip"

Comment: "Cabinet" is sometimes used to mean "booth".  (But in the US it's "ballot", not "voting paper".)

Comment: @Mari-LouA how is ‘voting slip’ more precise?

Comment: @Spagirl I forgot to ping you. The reference to being more precise was for "voting booth"  I suggested that voting slip was preferable to "voting paper". Was I mistaken? As soon as I read Hot Lick's "ballot" I realized that was the proper term, sometimes the right word comes hours, sometimes days later!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I somehow parsed that wrong and thought the precision was  in paper/slip, somehow I missed that full stop! Soz

Comment: Having been closely involved with elections for years, I never once heard “cabinet” used for “booth” nor do I think every-day English equates the two. That’s not to say that “cabinet” would be misinterpreted… just that it’s extremely unusual. 

That’s simply not the kind of thing texts are geared up for… the distinctions are both too obvious or too subtle but hardly quantifiable in dictionaries or thesauruses.

Use either "voting…” or "polling booth" and neither is truly comparable to “cabinet.”

Broadly, a “cabinet” is solid, closed, permanent and a “booth” flimsy, open, temporary.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard "cabinet" to mean "voting/polling booth". Usually a cabinet, with regards to government, is a small group of advisers, usually to a chief executive (The "Secretaries of ____" in America). Other than that, I would only think of a type of closing shelf you can put things in.

I thought at first that this might be British English, but I can't find anything in a search for it. Every reference turns up various political news about various cabinets (as in the groups of advisors).

Comment: In the US a "cabinet', outside of Washington DC, it the tall wooden display case for dishes that your grandmother left you.

Comment: Aye, hence the "closing shelf you can put things on". Cabinets are often used for non-display purposes, too.